# How do I ensure the "Publisher" field is populated for my ClickOnce *Bootstrapper*

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, certificate, bootstrapper

I've got an application that I deploy via ClickOnce. I do all the manifest generation/signing in an MSBuild script. Up until today we've been using a self-generated certificate, but now I've got a certificate from Verisign.

I can successfully sign my manifests using mage.exe and the new certificate and the Publisher field is shown properly when I run "myapp.Application" to install the app.

However, if I run the Bootstrapper (setup.exe) that I've generated for the app, the installer now says the Publisher is unknown (as if I haven't signed my manifests). I can't figure out what I need to do to the Bootstrapper to make the publisher show up properly in the install confirmation dialog. I've tried signing the Bootstrapper using SignTool but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Pseudo-code looks like:

1. Generate App Manifest (using mage.exe)
2. Sign App Manifest (using mage.exe)
3. Generate Deployment Manifest (using GenerateDeploymentManifest MSBuild task)
4. Sign Deployment Manifest (using mage.exe)
5. Generate Bootstrapper (using GenerateBootstrapper task)
6. Sign Boostrapper (using SignTool.exe)

Happy to post my code if there's no obvious problems with my workflow/tooling.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to sign the setup.exe using SignTool.

If it does not work, add a  'BeforePublish' Target by editing your application .csproj file.

Check [here](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/) and see this helps.

Don't forget to mark as answer, if it helps...!!!